# Convert time format 1w1d1h1m to number of hours in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have text in the format "1w1d1h1m" in an Excel workbook.

Is there any way that Excel can convert this time format into number of hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that weeks will be any number of digits, days 1 digit (0 to 6) and hours and minutes up to 2 digits this formula should work for any combination of w, d, h, m being present

`=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("w",A1&"w")-1)*168,0)+IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("d",A1)-1,1)*24,0)+IFERROR(LOOKUP(10^3,MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)-{1,2},{1,2})+0),0)+IFERROR(LOOKUP(10^3,MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)-{1,2},{1,2})+0)/60,0)`

Comment: th for the formula. I needed originally for working days & hours, so I adjusted it to accept week as 5 days and day as 8 hours. Works like charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the time value you are working with is a string, the following formula should do it:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("w",A1)-1)*168,0)+IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("w",A1)+1,SEARCH("d",A1)-SEARCH("w",A1)-1)*24,0)+IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("d",A1)+1,SEARCH("h",A1)-SEARCH("d",A1)-1),0)+IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("h",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("h",A1)-1)*(1/60),0)
```

If any of the elements of the time string are missing, then that time category is counted as 0.

Comment: Appreciate help, but it didn't work for me. I did not change formula and just typed "1w11h" in A1 field. It just displayed an error.

Comment: @Jaroslav, see my edited formula, which addresses the issue of varying components in the time strings :)

Comment: You're right - formula still not quite correct, assumes there is always the characters 'wdhm' in the string.

Answer (score 0):

A formula for this could be quite lengthy (as @chuff has just shown!) but if it is guaranteed that letters will never be immediately adjacent then I'd suggest replacing w by m, d by m, and h by m then Text to Columns using m as the delimiter and finish off with a formula `=168*A2+24*B2+C2+D2/60`, assuming your date started in `A2` (can be copied down).